# Chrome 108 changed the way 100% height is calculated when mobile keyborad is on

Tags: css, keyboard, height, viewport

Till now every major browser change the `viewport` height when mobile keyborad is on screen.

It is known that on IOS it can't be done since the `viewport` is calculated only once.

In the latest Chrome version 108 they added Dynamic, Small, Large viewport dimensions.
I tried using them in order to achive the shrinking `viewport` when mobile keyboard is on and it doesn't work as well.

Is it still possible to do it using CSS only?

Answer (score 2):

In version 108 Chrome is attempting to [match Safari's behavior](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/) by default which means that the virtual keyboard will not affect anything layout related; hence, it will not affect elements sized with viewport units.

If you just want the old Chrome behavior back you can use the [new `interactive-widget`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/#opting-in-to-a-different-behavior) key of the viewport meta tag to go back to the pre-108 behavior, e.g.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

Note though: `interactive-widget` is currently only supported in Chrome.